# Number of orders and combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, factorial, combinations

I have just done these two questions and I have answers for them but I am not sure if they are correct.

1. A jazz band is to give one concert in each of nine selected cities. Calculate the total number of orders in which these cities can be visited.

   I did this just using $9!$.
2. The student can select any four out of eight optional modules in semester $1$. And any five out of nine optional modules in semester $2$. Compute the total number of possible module selections for the whole year.

   For this is used my calculator and did $\binom{8}{4}+\binom{9}{5}$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number is correct, there are $9!$ permutations of the cities and each permutation corresponds to an order in which they can be visited.

The second one is not correct.  The distinction is that *for each* of the $\binom{8}{4}$ choices in semester 1, we can still make $\binom{9}{5}$ choices in semester 2.  So, it should be multiplication rather than addition.